# How to add inner shadow to UIView with rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I have to add an inner shadow to a `UIView` that has rounded corners.

I saw several answers on SO that add inner shadows to UIViews but they don't work as I want to, because they add the shadow to the whole rectangle, not accounting for the rounded corners.

See this image as an example of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add reference to the SO answers which have you checked and not filled your requirements ?

Comment: I have an idea but don't have time to validate it. Add subview with the same color which will be centered on the parent and will be with several pixels smaller. Like this you will have space from each side of the parent. On the parent turn on clipping subviews and add shadow to the inner view. Like this, you can have an inner shadow. Just check if the radius of the views is the same one.

Comment: Please add some code on what have you tried so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a trick. You give shadow and border to same view, the shadow will fall inside the view. please make sure the background color of view is clear. use the below code for reference.

```
yourView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 6
yourView.layer.masksToBounds = true
yourView.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
yourView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
yourView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.width / 2
```